# How gci (get child item) can print file contents?

Tags: powershell

Searching the web for a `findstr` equivalent for Powershell I found [this site](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2006/06/03/pshfindstr), which suggests using the the Cmdlet [`gci`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx) (get child items) and [`select-string`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176956.aspx). However, `gci` doesn't print the content of a file, instead it prints the directory content. How the pipelining in this case works, how can `gci` and `select-string` filter the content of a file (without piplining it first to the `get-content`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Select-String` accepts pipeline input. When you pipe FileInfo objects, they bind to the InputObject parameter. The following two commands are equivalent:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem C:\test.txt | Select-String -Pattern logfile

PS> Select-String -InputObject (Get-ChildItem C:\test.txt) -Pattern logfile
```

Answer (score 3):

The `select-string` cmdlet recieves a `System.IO.FileInfo` object from the pipeline. Thus it is able to determine which part of its parameters are file names and which are the strings to look for. See [Select-string](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) at Technet.

Comment: Ok I understand now, it is select-string which reads the file contents, thanks.